# How to Add Private git repo as a submodule in another git repo

Tags: git, github-actions, git-submodules, private-repository

How to add a private git repository as a submodule in another git repository?

locally when i do `git submodule update` it works fine, but in the github action runner, it fails with error stating **url not found** at the checkout step.

Here's how i have configured my workflow file.

```
jobs:
  update_submodules:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true

      # - name: Clone submodule
      #   run: git submodule update --init --recursive

      - name: Pull & update submodules recursively
        run: |
          git submodule update --init --recursive
          git submodule update --recursive --remote
```

It fails in the second step.

Answer (score 4):

You could not have to code the `submodule update init`, as it is an option of the `action/checkout` itself.

For instance, [`actions/checkout` issue 116](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/116#issuecomment-644419389) shows:

> - Generate PAT: https://github.com/settings/tokens
> - And add the secret: `https://github.com/<-- username -->/<-- repo -->/settings/secrets/new`, give it a unique name say `MY_REPO_PAT`.
> - Configure action as follows:
>
> ```yaml
>    steps:
>    - name: Checkout
>      uses: actions/checkout@v2
>      with:
>        token: ${{ secrets.MY_REPO_PAT }}
>        submodules: recursive
> ```

[However](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/287#issuecomment-1368025325):

> Using a PAT in one GitHub action can affect other GitHub actions apparently.
> For example if you have a tagging/versioning step that commits to the same branch by tagging it, the default `GITHUB_TOKEN` prevents recursive pipeline triggers.
> After trying the fixes here that advocate the use of a PAT to download a submodule, in my case, the PAT stayed on for the step that committed the tag. **This causes the pipeline to go into recursive builds repeatedly tagging and releasing**.

---

Or (alternative), [issue 287](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/287#issuecomment-707304140):

> I have a solution that doesn't require personal access tokens but keeps the reference to the child repo commit in one place (using git submodules)
>
> ```yaml
>    - name: clone submodule
>      uses: actions/checkout@v2
>      with:
>        repository: <org name>/<repo name>
>        path: path
>        ssh-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
>        persist-credentials: true
>
>    - name: checkout submodule
>      run: |
>        git submodule init
>        git submodule update
> ```
>
> Although the action checks out `master`, the `git submodule` commands check out the correct commit, this avoids having to keep the ref in github actions.

Regarding that last issue (287), [Matthijs Kooijman](https://github.com/matthijskooijman) also describes  [how to setup and manage a Github App](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/287#issuecomment-1315458401).

And [Štěpán Jákl](https://github.com/stepanjakl) [adds](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/287#issuecomment-1315511483):

> I also realized that you can simply do this using the checkout action to include multiple submodule deploy keys.
> I am surprised it hasn't been mentioned here yet.
>
> ```yaml
> ...
>     steps:
>       - uses: actions/checkout@v3
>          with:
>            ssh-key: |
>              ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_SUBMODULE_1 }}
>              ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_SUBMODULE_2 }}
>           submodules: 'recursive'
> ...
> ```
>
> Just remember the keys must be generated with a link/comment to the repository e.g.
>
> ```
> ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "git@github.com:owner/repo.git"
> ```
>
> The GH checkout can then connect the key with the correct repository.

---

Still in [issue 287](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/287#issuecomment-1830291196), Q4 0223:

> There's an official action to handle GH App tokens.
> Here's how my workflow ended up:
>
> ```yaml
> jobs:
>   test-submodules:
>     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
>     steps:
>     - name: Get token from Github App
>       uses: actions/create-github-app-token@v1
>       id: app_token
>       with:
>         app-id: ${{ secrets.APP_ID }}
>         private-key: ${{ secrets.APP_PEM }}
>         # owner is required, otherwise the creds will fail the checkout step
>         owner: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
>
>     - name: Checkout from GitHub
>       uses: actions/checkout@v4
>       with:
>         submodules: true
>         token: ${{ steps.app_token.outputs.token }}
>     
>     - name: Print .gitmodules
>       run: cat .gitmodules
> ```
>
> In the GH app side:
>
> - provide it with contents permission - minimum
> - install the app in the submodule repo AND in the repo where the workflow is (otherwise checkout will fail to clone the main repo)